# How to remove array by it's value in php?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array and i want to remove array which keyval is 60138. How to remove specific array using it's value ?

```
Array
    (
    [name] => Hydrangeas.jpg
    [keyval] => 23905
    )
    Array
    (
        [name] => Chrysanthemum.jpg
        [keyval] => 87936
    )
    Array
    (
        [name] => Penguins.jpg
        [keyval] => 60138
    )
    Array
    (
        [name] => Tulips.jpg
        [keyval] => 82902
    )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why isn't your array in the `keyval => name` form? This way, you just do `unset($array[keyval])`.

Comment: `array_filter`? I am sure a duplicate can be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$array = array(
    // here is all your array with name + keyval
);

// Loop throught each array
foreach ($array as $key => $subarray) {
    // If keyval has the value you want to delete : remove it from main $array
    if ($subarray['keyval'] == 60138) {
        unset($array[$key];
    }
}
```